# plugin for eclipse which show me byte code of java program

Tags: java, eclipse, bytecode

I want to see bytecode and low level versions of any java code. Is there any plug-in available which will show me bytecode of java source code? I also want to see low level versions of java code. I want to see the full flow of program from java source code to low level language. Is this possible?

Comment: Google first link gave me this http://asm.ow2.org/eclipse/  .

Comment: how deep you want to go? from java to assembly??